# How to pass String and Range in UDF

Tags: excel, vba

For calculating purposes, I need to pass a worksheet name and specific (single) cell range in UDF and use them. As there is no way to pass the worksheet directly as an UDF argument, I would like to pass the worksheet name instead as string and the Range as the UDF arguments. In order to demonstrate the problem in simpler way, I have showed the following code only to get value of the range of that worksheet name by below:

```
Option Explicit
Function test(ws As String, r1 As Range) As Variant
test = Sheets(ws).r1.Value
End Function
```

Now If I enter `=test("MySheet",C2)` in another worksheet of the same workbook, it is showing `#Value!`. However, if I change the Vba code to the following:

```
Option Explicit
Function test(ws As String, r1 As Range) As Variant
test = Sheets(ws).Range("C2").Value
End Function
```

it is showing correct value form the C2 of MySheet worksheet. So I assume the problem is in passing the Range and using it in the Vba code. What is that problem? Anybody can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are passing a `Range` object, then it already knows what worksheet it's in. You cant change what worksheet it references like that.

Instead, pass 2 strings if you want it to be dynamic.

```
Function test(ws As String, r As String) As Variant
  test = Worksheets(ws).Range(r).Value
End Function
```

and then:

```
=test("MySheet","C2")
```

You can, however, just use that cell's address as the string:

```
Function test(ws As String, r As Range) As Variant
  test = Worksheets(ws).Range(r.Address).Value
End Function
```

so you can use:

```
=test("MySheet",C2)
```